# Why does selecting text only "copy" it (as in copy and paste) circumstantially?

Tags: x11, clipboard, libreoffice

One of the most user-friendly features of Linux is that highlighting or selecting text will automatically *copy* it so that it can be pasted upon a middle-
click.  However, this can also be a point of frustration because this behavior only works under certain conditions.  For example, it works consistently in Chrome, in terminals, and many GTK apps, but strangely, not in LibreOffice.

Is there any way to make selecting text *copy* the text under every circumstance?

Comment: It works consistently in Chrome for you? Hmm, I want your copy of Chrome!

Comment: As far as I know, it is only [libre|open]office that has issues with this. They seem to have screwed with the X selection buffer for some reason.

Comment: Not an answer, but using Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V will do as a workaround in many situations (except in a terminal like konsole where Ctrl-Shift-C and Ctrl-Shift-V are used.)